# Google Sheets - How to extract words from a cell using regexextract

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, regexextract

I have a spreadsheet with many rows like this:

```
Arkonor 16m³Crimson +5%Prime +10%Flawless +15%

Bistot 16m³Triclinic +5%Monoclinic +10%Cubic +15%

Crokite 16m³Sharp +5%Crystalline +10%Pellucid +15%
```

How do I extract words from these cells? Example, in the first row, I would like to extract words Arkonor, Crimson, Prime and Flawless, one in each cell if possible.

Comment: 4 rows if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(
 D1,"\b\w[^A-z]*\b"," "),"\W+"," "),"[0-9]+","")," m "," "))," "))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much! it solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

```
=TRANSPOSE(IFERROR({REGEXEXTRACT(D1,"Arkonor"),
                    REGEXEXTRACT(D1,"Crimson"),
                    REGEXEXTRACT(D1,"Prime"),
                    REGEXEXTRACT(D1,"Flawless")}))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply, and sorry I think I did not explain the question correctly, I will edit it. I cannot set values for the words, because I have 200 rows and each row there are different words, so I need a regex to extract words from the cell, no matter what is written there.